# Can you have multiple different pages on 1 GH repositories

Tags: github, url, github-pages

Is it possible to have 1 GH repository but with two different pages on 2 different URLs? If yes, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

To achieve this have 2+ files in a repository. (It does not matter if it's HTML. HTM, Markdown, or whatever) The URL will be formatted like this: `<your_GH_username>.github.io/<repository_name>/<file_path>` The file path can not have `../` or `./` at the beginning for the root directory. And the files do not need to have a file extension.